# Android MediaPlayer Mute and unmute

Tags: android, media-player, mute

I am playing a video using `MediaPlayer`. Now there is a mute/unmute button. This toggle button should set first the video play without sound, on second press it should make its volume to its initial state. I tried with `AudioManager.setMicrophoneMute` method. It did not work. How it can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `AudioManager.setStreamMute(int streamType, boolean on)`
Setting it to true will change stream's volume to 0, and false restores volume value.
More information at
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setStreamMute(int,boolean)

Answer (score 0):

The `setMicrophoneMute()`  mutes the microphone (obviously), this is an input device. Microphone does not participate in audio playback and therefore muting it has no effect.

You can use `MediaPlayer.setVolume()` to mute/unmute the output. For an idea how to implement this see this [thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/8b760f2372274e74).

Comment: To use setVolume, I have to pass the both left volume and right volume, both of them are in float. But before setting the Mediaplayer volume to zero, I have to get the current volume first so that I can reset it to the same volume at the time unmute. In the above mentioned thread, AudioManager.getStreamVolume is used to get the volume, it is giving a single int value as volume. How this can be used to at the time of unmute?